# Finding a circle in an undirected graph

Tags: python-3.x, graph, find, geometry

I wrote a small function which should find a circle in a given (undiricted) graph and returns true if it finds a circle, false if not.

```
def dfs(v,last):
    if vis[v] == True:
        return True
    vis[v] = True
    c = False
    for el in adj[v]:
         if el == last:
             adj[v].remove(el)
         else:
             c = c or dfs(el,v)
    return c
```

The adjacencylist is a dict looks like this:`adj ={1: [2], 2: [1,3], 3: [2]}`.
The other dictionary is to check if the knot has been visited or not. `vis = {1: False, 2: False, 3: False}`
The problem i have is that it seemed to work for the given list in the example but for others it gives me a false result (for example: `adj = {1: [2,4], 2: [1,5], 4: [1,5], 5:[2,4]}`
Can you help me with the issue or tell me how to find a better way for this problem. I don't want to import any other moduls.

Comment: `adj ={1: [2], 2: [1,3], 3: [2]}` does not include a cycle ... is that intended?

Comment: yes the function should return true if this is a circle, false if not.

Comment: adj = {1: [2,4], 2: [1,5], 4: [1,5], 5:[2,4]} is a circle but it returns "False"

Comment: Just so your know, the standard term in graph theory is 'cycle' rather than 'circle'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the remove-statement. Try the following:

```
def dfs(v,last):
    if v in vis:
        return True
    vis.append(v)
    c = False
    current_adj_list = list(adj[v])
    for el in current_adj_list:
        if el == last:
            adj[el].remove(v)
        else:
            c = c or dfs(el,v)
    return c

adj = {1: [2,4], 2:[1,5,4], 4: [1,2], 5: [2]}
vis = []

print(dfs(1,None))
```

Explanation: You were deleting the edge from the currently visiting node to it's successor's. In the loop you were therefore deleting the same element over and over again from the same list.
However, you really want to delete the edges from the successors. Therefore,

```
adj[v].remove(el)
```

became

```
adj[el].remove(v)
```

Secondly, we need to copy the adjacency list with

```
current_adj_list = list(adj[v])
```

because we edit the list deeper in the recursion, changing the order of elements, and thereby (possibly) ruining the loop in a higher recursion level.

Comment: adj = {1: [2,4], 2:[1,5,4], 4: [1,2], 5: [2]} is giving me a false result now. Your correction helped me though.

Comment: Found the problem. I was overriding the loop-array deeper in the recursion. I updated the solution, and added an explanation

Comment: it doesn't work for two graphs who are not connected. eg adj ={1: [4, 6], 2:[7, 3], 3:[7, 2], 4:[5. 1], 5:[4], 6:[1], 7:[2, 3]}

Comment: Of course it does not, using this implementation. This is for a connected graph only - after all, you look for loops by traversing the graph. I thought that you knew that. If you want to implement a complete DFS, you have to "strike out" nodes already visited, and restart the DFS on the remaining nodes, until all have been visited.